# Open database of industrial companies and products, with bill of materials

Tags: data-request, products, industry

I'm looking for open database of industrial companies and products, with bill of materials. For example - company name, industry, list of production. For each product - name, code, bill of material etc.

Updated:

something like http://zinc.docking.org/, but for products.

Comment: For the entire world? Or a particular country/area?

Comment: It would be great for entire world, or for some industries (metallurgy, petrochemistry, car components etc).

Answer (score 4):

The National (US) Renewable Energy Laboratory provide open-source LCI (Life Cycle Inventories) for products, which contain inputs to and outputs from production of products.
From the "on the project" page:

> The U.S. Life Cycle Inventory (LCI) Database is a publicly available database that allows users to objectively review and compare analysis results that are based on similar data collection and analysis methods.

You can get to the site at: [This link](http://www.nrel.gov/lci/)

See an example of an inventory of Ethylene, at plant [here](https://www.lcacommons.gov/nrel/process/show/32120?qlookup=&max=35&hfacet=&hfacetCat=&loc=&year=&dtype=&crop=&index=25&numfound=3160&offset=)

Comment: This is not quite what I'm looking for. DB contain the raw input and output for typical technological processes, not properties and bom for products. Input and output materials a not in the list of products. Sorry.

Comment: no. I'm sorry. Hope you'll find what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

I heard about a startup launching a platform for business assets, maybe you don't want to buy or sell stuffs, but they will aggregate a lot of stuff:
http://theassets.co

Comment: It doesn't allow without beta-registration, but signing up was fail. I see, it's a very-very new startup.

Comment: I have no idea, what is that site is made for.

Answer (score 0):

There is also ELCD, https://eplca.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ELCD3/, and this https://www.globallcadataaccess.org/, and https://eplca.jrc.ec.europa.eu/LCDN/.

Hope it helps, Regards and stay safe,

António Martins